# Would changing mysql port in xampp will delete my website on local server?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am a complete beginner in website development.

While Downloading Mysql on my pc, it gives me an error - **3306 is already in use** - during type and networking settings.
I made a local website on WordPress on my laptop with xampp and that port number 3306 is in use there.

Now, I am asking if I change my port number, would it delete my local website?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your DB port won't delete your local website.

The only problem you may encounter is the link between your project and your database. Be sure to update your `wp-config.php` file in your project with the new database port you will have set.